# Python: Unable to generate unique count for 10 counts

Tags: python-3.x

for my practical work. This question requires me to generate 10 separate unique counts from a range (1, 1000). Each count supposes to generate a total of 10 numbers of odd and even numbers. I can only use a while loop to execute 10 unique counts. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

SAMPLE OUTPUT QUOTED

- Out of 100 random numbers, 56 were odd, and 44 were even.
- Out of 100 random numbers, 60 were odd, and 40 were even.
- Out of 100 random numbers, 47 were odd, and 53 were even.
- Out of 100 random numbers, 54 were odd, and 46 were even.
- Out of 100 random numbers, 48 were odd, and 52 were even.
- Out of 100 random numbers, 53 were odd, and 47 were even.
- Out of 100 random numbers, 46 were odd, and 54 were even.
- Out of 100 random numbers, 52 were odd, and 48 were even.
- Out of 100 random numbers, 53 were odd, and 47 were even.
- Out of 100 random numbers, 48 were odd, and 52 were even.

MY OUTPUT

- Out of 100 random numbers, 51 were odd, 49 were even.
- Out of 100 random numbers, 51 were odd, 49 were even.
- Out of 100 random numbers, 51 were odd, 49 were even.
- Out of 100 random numbers, 51 were odd, 49 were even.
- Out of 100 random numbers, 51 were odd, 49 were even.
- Out of 100 random numbers, 51 were odd, 49 were even.
- Out of 100 random numbers, 51 were odd, 49 were even.
- Out of 100 random numbers, 51 were odd, 49 were even.
- Out of 100 random numbers, 51 were odd, 49 were even.
- Out of 100 random numbers, 51 were odd, 49 were even.

MY CODE

```
import random

# loop counter for 100 random numbers
loop = 0
# part of end result
msg = 'Out of 100 random numbers,'
# count for even numbers 
even_count = 0
# count for odd numbers
odd_count = 0
# gen  number counter
gen_num01 = False
#loop count event
loop_count = 0
```

#Counter for 10 loop_count event
    loop_count_event = False

while loop_count < 10:

```
loop_count += 1 

#while count for 100 random numbers 
while loop < 100:

    num_gen = random.randint(1,1000)
    loop += 1

    if num_gen % 2 == 0:

        even_count += 1
        msg02 = 'were even.'

    elif num_gen % 2 > 0:

        odd_count += 1
        msg01 = 'were odd,'

if gen_num01 == False:

    print(msg, odd_count, msg01, even_count, msg02)
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I need to know how to generate 10 unique counts, with x number of odd and y number of even numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not initializing the loop counter each time, so the inner loop isn't executing, and you are not initializing the counters either.

You also don't need to set msg01 & msg02 on each number since you always initialize them to the same thing.

Try this:

```
import random

# loop counter for 100 random numbers
loop = 0
# part of end result
msg = 'Out of 100 random numbers,'
# count for even numbers 
even_count = 0
# count for odd numbers
odd_count = 0
# gen  number counter
gen_num01 = False
#loop count event
loop_count = 0
#Counter for 10 loop_count event loop_count_event = False
msg02 = 'were even.'
msg01 = 'were odd,'


while loop_count < 10:

    loop_count += 1 
    even_count = 0
    odd_count = 0
    loop = 0

    #while count for 100 random numbers 
    while loop < 100:

        num_gen = random.randint(1,1000)
        loop += 1

        if num_gen % 2 == 0:
            even_count += 1
        else:
            odd_count += 1

if gen_num01 == False:
    print(msg, odd_count, msg01, even_count, msg02)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your results are not uncommon, this is simply the way pseudo-random generators work. If you are using > python 3.2, then go for `random.randrange(0, 100)`. Here's a quote from the [documentation of the function](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/random.html#):

> Changed in version 3.2: randran
>   ge() is more sophisticated about
>   producing equally distributed values. Formerly it used a style like
>   int(random()*n) which could produce slightly uneven distributions.

Otherwise, another solution may be `int(random.uniform(0, 1) * 100)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinitialise `loop` to zero *each time* through the outer loop.

What's happening is that for the first outer loop, the `loop` variable is going from zero to a hundred (or thereabouts). Then, on subsequent outer loops, the inner loop isn't running because its control variable is *already* too high.

That's why you're getting exactly the same counts for odd and even, despite the fact they're not zeroed either, which would normally result in the values accumulating.

The following code shows what I mean:

```
import random

msg = 'Out of 100 random numbers,'

for loop_count in xrange(10):
    even_count = 0
    odd_count = 0

    for loop in xrange(100):
        num_gen = random.randint(1,1000)

        if num_gen % 2 == 0:

            even_count += 1
            msg02 = 'were even.'

        elif num_gen % 2 > 0:

            odd_count += 1
            msg01 = 'were odd,'

    print(msg, odd_count, msg01, even_count, msg02)
```

and it gives the output:

```
('Out of 100 random numbers,', 48, 'were odd,', 52, 'were even.')
('Out of 100 random numbers,', 52, 'were odd,', 48, 'were even.')
('Out of 100 random numbers,', 46, 'were odd,', 54, 'were even.')
('Out of 100 random numbers,', 43, 'were odd,', 57, 'were even.')
('Out of 100 random numbers,', 44, 'were odd,', 56, 'were even.')
('Out of 100 random numbers,', 42, 'were odd,', 58, 'were even.')
('Out of 100 random numbers,', 49, 'were odd,', 51, 'were even.')
('Out of 100 random numbers,', 54, 'were odd,', 46, 'were even.')
('Out of 100 random numbers,', 57, 'were odd,', 43, 'were even.')
('Out of 100 random numbers,', 55, 'were odd,', 45, 'were even.')
```